# Running a .bat file in Scheduled Task

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I am using a Windows Server 2008 machine where I need to run a batch file as a Scheduled Task. The scheduled batch file is not running, but when I click the batch file manually its running with no problem.

The Content of the batch file is as follows:

```
  cd E:\SOAPUI\soapui-2.0.2\bin
  e:
  testrunner.bat -sDev_Test -a -j -f "D:\DocRepos\LensWebSvc\SOAPUI-Reports(Lens)"                 
  "D:\DocRepos\LensWebSvc\SOAPUI\LensWebServiceTest(Lens)-soapui-project.xml"
```

Can anyone help me to run the batch file in scheduled task?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a few things.  Make sure you've set the task to start in the same path that the batch file is located.  Also, make sure the account running the task has permission to run the task and access the location of the batch file.