# Task scheduler cannot open batch file when set to run whether user is logged on or not

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

I am unable to get the Task Scheduler to run .bat files while I am logged off. I have a a production .bat file I want to use, but for my troubleshooting purposes I am using C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.bat

test.bat is very simple. All it contains is:
taskkill /im notepad.exe

It runs successfully on its own. If I have Notepad open and I double-click test.bat then the cmd window flashes and Notepad dies. The .bat file is not the problem.

The task I created in Task Scheduler is "Test taskkill" (without the quotes). I can see its location in Windows Explorer: C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Test taskkill

If the task is set to run only when the user is logged on then the task works. With this setting, I can right-click on it > run and I get the same behavior as if I double-click the .bat file. That means the task is configured correctly.

If I set it to run whether or not the user is logged on then when I right-click > run nothing obvious happens. The job is reported as having been run successfully in the history, but Notepad survives. I know that I am using the proper credentials for the account that I am configuring to run the task. That account is the local administrator.

This issue appears similar to issues other have had in the past:

[Running a .bat file in Scheduled Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239560/problem-running-a-bat-file-in-scheduled-task)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d47d116e-10b9-44f0-9a30-7406c86c2fbe/scheduled-task-wont-run-bat-file?forum=winservermanager

The thread in the second link seemed to resolve an identical issue for many people with the suggestion that the account used to run the task requires explicit permission to the .bat file and all files that the .bat file modifies. This was very promising (if an annoying requirement). However, I have confirmed or assigned explicit permissions for the local administrator to the following areas, and I am still not successful:

- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\
- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.bat
- C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\
- C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Test taskkill

Additionally, I have confirmed that the local administrator account is in the local administrators group.

Am I missing some other permissions that needs to be set? Is there something else I should be looking at? Thanks!

Comment: did you check the "run with highest privileges" checkbox?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I should have specified that, but I did indeed do so.

Comment: I may have resolved this. I will let you know soon (probably tomorrow).

Comment: I have exactly the same issue in windows 10

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have resolved this problem with help from a contractor who was doing some other work for my institution.

In the properties window for the task, on the Action tab, when creating or editing the action that opens the batch file (in my case test.bat), there is the "Program/script:" field and there is also a "Start in (optional):" field. I previously had the "Program/script:" field containing the full path to the file, ending with the file name, and I had the "Start in (optional):" field null. This configuration appears to work without issue when the task is set to "Run only when user is logged on" in the General tab of the task's properties window. However, this configuration does not work when the task is set to "Run whether user is logged on or not".

In order to resolve the problem, I changed the action so that the "Program/script:" field contained only the file name, not the file path. I put the file path in the "Start in (optional):" field. This configuration works when the task is set to "Run only when user is logged on"! I have tested with the task running on a trigger and also with running it manually.

Comment: doesn't work for me, only if i change the selection of radio button. maybe you can upload some screenshots how exactly you populated the fields.

Answer (score 3):

Verifying the following has worked for me:

1) 'Run if user is not logged in' option in Task Scheduler does not work for programs that is interactive mode. Example notepad, clock. Tasks will not run interactively. Make sure your program does not requires any interactive actions.

2)Check the “Start in (optional) “ If your program path is not one of the system paths. You have better to add you program path in it. On the "Program/Script" enter only the name of the program, and enter the path of your script in "Start in".

3)The user account you setup for your program must have permission not only to run your program itself and but also to run all other program that related to your program.

Here is a sample program:

On C:\myprogram\folderOne\test.cmd

```
date /t >> c:\Temp\testAuto.log
date /t >> c:\temp\testAuto.log
echo ----->> c:\temp\testAuto.log
cls
exit
```

-Create a Tasks, selecting on General>SecurityOptions "Run whether user is logged on or not"
-Enter on Action>Program/script: test.cmd
 on "Start in" C:\myprogram\folderOne
-Run, you might see the cmd windows open and closes very quickly. The testAuto.log file should be in c:\tmp folder.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps. My issue was using a interactive program (in particular Excel) as well.

Creating the 2 empty folders (Desktop) solved it. Create both even if you are running on x64.

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

I debugged my code and realised the code exited at this line

```
ExcelFile excelFile = new ExcelFile(directory, filename);
```

I read this solution somewhere and I cannot find the URL now.

Comment: This one worked for me when using excel macros in the bat file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me. Same thing, I had a task that executes an excel macro. I didn't really expected this would work but it made the magic. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try this as well..

Resolved the "Run whether user is logged on or not" by setting the “Log on as Batch Job” security policy.

Here is details on the setting… https://web.archive.org/web/20220921172736/https://danblee.com/log-on-as-batch-job-rights-for-task-scheduler/

You may take another approach, but here is the steps…

1. I updated the default domain group policy by adding my admin account (that I fire the task with) to the “Log on as Batch Job” security policy. (Even though ADMIN group is listed, and I am using an admin account)
2. I forced GPUPDATE on the client
3. Rebooted the client
4. Looked at the policy on the client to make sure it made it over from the DC
5. Set the task "Run whether user is logged on or not"
6. Ran the task on demand and it worked creating a PDF file.
7. Logged out and ran the task at scheduled time and it worked creating a PDF file.

Comment: every time this is the issue on my servers

Comment: link is dead.  (I think these 3 words are enough but got a stupid prompt "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length" !)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but it was related to the fact that there was a space in the path of my executable batch file. I have removed the space and now it works fine.

Comment: So your issue was that you had a typo? That is probably not very useful for others.

Comment: No, it was not a typo!
The space was really in the path because the path of the batch file had a space. What I did was changed the path of the batch removing the space; i.e. it was on "D:\My Jobs\executethis.bat" to "D:\MyJobs\executethis.bat"
I needed to create a new directory without the space.

Answer (score 0):

What work for me was make sure that the path is available.

i used net use Z: \computername\folder /persistent:yes

then the xxcopy  /s /c /d /e /i /y D:*.* z:\BackupBat

I notice all my other .bat work fine only the one with the reference to a map folder was the one no running, so that need to be the problem. with these change the bat file runs good.

Answer (score -4):

It might be because you don't have permission. I was facing the same problem and i found the solution like this -
Open Task Scheduler right click on your task and than select properties option.
In properties click on General tab and then click on 'User Group or User' and select the appropriate user.